# How to create user in authentication plugin?

Tags: moodle

I want to write a customized authentication plugin for Moodle 3.10

When a user tries to login with loginform, the plugin will check credentials with an external API. Only if matches the user will be logged in. If account does not exists, it will be created.

This is how far I came:

```
class auth_plugin_externalapi extends auth_plugin_base {
   

    user_login($username, $password){
        global $DB;
        
        $user = login_via_api($username, $password);
    
        if(empty($user)){
           return false;
        }
    
        if(!$DB->get_record('user', array('username' => $api_data->username)){
            user_create_user($user);
        }
    
        return true;
    }
}
```

This approach fails, because when `user_login` is called via `lib/moodlelib.php` in method `authenticate_user_login`, then the user is created twice.

Is there a specific way to create user through authentication plugins in moodle? Or do I need to customize the code in `lib/moodlelib.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moodle authentication plugins should not be directly creating user accounts, they should just determine whether or not the user has authenticated successfully and the details of the user.

The Moodle core code then handles the process of either updating the existing user account, with the details provided, or creating a new account with those details (as long as 'authpreventaccountcreation' is not set). Either way, the core code then starts a login session with the identified user account.

The easiest way to proceed from where you are, would be something like this:

```
class auth_plugin_externalapi extends auth_plugin_base {
    private static $userinfo;

    public function user_login($username, $password){
        self::$userinfo = login_via_api($username, $password);
        return (bool)self::$userinfo;
    }

    public function get_userinfo($username) {
        if (!self::$userinfo) {
            return false;
        }
        if (self::$userinfo->username !== $username) {
            return false;
        }
        return (array)self::$userinfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: So this means, user_login may return true, but when get_userinfo returns false, the user can't be created. So in short, you can login, but the creation of your account may fail?

Comment: And I am using Moodle 3.10, your link referes to Moodle 4. In the documentation of Moodle 3.120 i cant find anything about events